# How to allocate more memory to main partition?

Tags: linux, raspberry-pi, disk-usage

I'm trying to setup a raspberry pi 3 for linux use, and I'm running into trouble with partitions. I'm very new to linux use and disk management so this is probably my misunderstanding.

I don't have enough space, by my interpretation, to use more disk space but fdisk -l shows that it recognizes the available space on the SD card:
https://i.stack.imgur.com/xUQEa.png

but my filesystem can't make use of this space:
https://i.stack.imgur.com/0hWXE.png

How do I allow it to use the remaining ~29GB?

Answer (score 0):

You should NOT (ABSOLUTELY NOT) use fdisk or cfdisk to resize partitions with operating systems on them, as this will most likely make them unable to boot. Install Gparted and resize the partition there.

Answer (score 0):

From:

$ man resize2fs

The  resize2fs program will resize ext2, ext3, or ext4 file systems

Should be:

$ sudo resize2fs /dev/mmcblk0p1 26G